# regular expression to match emails

Tags: php, javascript, regex

i am stuck at particular problem i have username field where on only alphabets numbers and . - and _ are allowed and should always start with alphabet

here are examples what are accepted

```
someone@mydomain.com
something1234@mydomain.com
someething.something@mydomain.com
something-something@mydomain.com
something_something@mydomain.com
something_1234@mydomain.com 
something.123@mydomain.com
something-456@mydomain.com
```

what i have done till now is

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+@mydomain.com
```

this matches all my requirement except of problem it dosent match

```
someone@mydomain.com
someont123@mydomain.com
```

but it even matches

```
someone_someone_something@mydomain.com
```

which is not required i am really not getting how to solve this one thing i tried is

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]{0}[a-zA-Z0-9]+@mydomain.com
```

but this is also not solving my problem now it accepts everything like

```
something+455@mydomain.com
```

which is not required    please help me

Comment: Regex for email is tricky. See this tutorial http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: What is this for - to validate  *any* E-Mail address, or to check a user name for a specific site?

Comment: If you're not already, you might consider using a [Regex analyzer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772594/regular-expression-explained-with-words) to step through your Regex against sample data. Regex Coach tells me *No sub-match at 7* for `someone@mydomain.com` and highlights the `[._-]{1,1}` block.

Comment: @Pekka its to check for username everything to left of /@mydomain.com will be used for username

Comment: `something+455@mydomain.com` is a valid email address. Why do you want to block it?

Comment: @Quentin i have been instructed  to allow only above specified address for some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the `-` or `.` optional, then you have to replace the `{1,1}` (quantifier: once) with an `?` (quantifier: one or none) here:

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@mydomain.com
```

The reason this regex also matches shorter addresses without delimiter `-._` is that you don't assert the whole string, but just some part of it. Use start `^` and end `$` anchors:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@mydomain\.com$
```

Comment: hey thanks this worked i tried with ? earlier but somehow it didn't work i guess there some other mistake but anyways its going good now thanks

Comment: will fail on `'a@domain.com'`, `'jean.claude.van.damme@domain.com'` and `'bob@maketing.department@domain.com'`, which all are valid emails

Answer (score 1):

This is why we have [`filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

If email address is valid, then you just have to check if it ends with `@domain.com`. That could be done with [`strrpos($email, '@domain.com')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

Comment: That's not what OP asked. A single domain and a constrained address format was to be asserted, not all valid email address variations.

Comment: Yes i don't validate against all valid email address but only those which i have specified but anyways thanks

Comment: OP didn't specify emails that are not valid, so this assumption was correct. Upvote.